# Data validation on worksheet change vba

Tags: vba, excel, validation

I am trying to do some data validation in excel that would limit the user entry based on previous user input. I would like this to be updated based on worksheet change. The code is as follows:

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
'Checks if cell is Record or Assumption and applies appropriate data validation
Dim Cell As Range
Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Column = 59 Or 72 Or 85 Or 98 Or 111 Then 'Refers to the columns that require Rec/Ass
        Set Cell = Target.Offset(0, 3)
'MsgBox Cell & " " & Target.Value 'USED TO ERROR CHECK
        If Target.Value = "N/A" Then
            Cell.Validation.Delete
            Cell.Value = vbNullString
            Cell.Offset(0, 1).Validation.Delete
            Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = vbNullString
        Else
            If Target.Value = "Record" Then
                With Cell.Validation
                    .Delete
                    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=Record"
                End With
            ElseIf Target.Value = "Assumption" Then
                Cell.Validation.Delete
                Cell.Value = vbNullString
                Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = vbNullString
            End If
        End If
        Set Cell = ActiveCell
    End If

    If Target.Column = 62 Or 75 Or 88 Or 101 Or 114 Then 'Refers to the columns that require Doc Type
        Desig = Application.VLookup(Target.Value, Sheets("Record Source Chart").Range("RecordDesig"), 21, False)
        If Target.Value = "" Then Exit Sub
        Else
            Set Cell = Target.Offset(0, 1)
            With Cell.Validation
                .Delete
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=" & Desig
            End With
    End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I am having an issue with the second if statement. When I run this code, the second data.validation is not added - I think this is because the cell is blank until I update it, but even after I update it the validation does not go through. Also, if I delete `If Target.Value = "" Then Exit Sub`even though the Target.Column = 59, the second if statement runs and returns a "Type Mismatch" error. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this :

```
If Target.Column = 62 Or 75 Or 88 Or 101 Or 114 Then
```

to :

```
If Target.Column = 62 Or Target.Column = 75 Or Target.Column = 88 Or Target.Column = 101 Or Target.Column = 114 Then
```

Or better yet, change to `Select Case`:

```
Select Case Target.Column
    Case 62, 75, 88, 101, 114
        ' rest of your code goes here...

End Select
```

***Note***: You need to modify it also for the first time:

```
If Target.Column = 59 Or 72 Or 85 Or 98 Or 111 Then 'Refers to the columns that require Rec/Ass
```

Comment: Wow I totally didn't know about the "Case" clause. Thank you so much for the help, I think that solved it. Issue was I was constantly changing my "Target.Column" by offsetting. Your first solution didn't work, it resulted in the same problem I was facing beforehand. The "Select Case" seemed to have fixed it, thank you once again!